# How to compute a linear system using lapack/blas, when matrix is psd?

Tags: lapack

I have a matrix $A$ and matrices $B_i=L_i^\mathsf{T} M_i L_i$. I want to estimate  the following quantity for $i\in [1,n]$,

```
\begin{eqnarray}
m_i^\mathsf{T}(A-B_i)^{-1}m_i
\end{eqnarray}
```

I use lapack/blas to obtain $B_i$s but when I want to compute the linear system  $(A-B_i)x = m_i$, using lapack, the routine dpotrf and dpotrs, they require that the matrix be in the lower triangle form or upper triangle form. How to compute the above computation using lapack/blas? Is there any example in C or C++? Copying from a Full matrix to lower triangle form is costly, is there any method which can perform multiplication for $B_i$ directly in the lower triangle form, so we don't need to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

They don't require it to be in the triangular form. They only *refer* to the triangular parts. But here you can directly use a psd solver which is `?posv` or the refined version `?posvx`